# I have created a lightning datatable in LWC and now want a url field to open a modal

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-community

I am not sure what is that i have to add in the code to make it open in a modal
[image]

Comment: Hey, you can't open a modal with LWCs unless with CSS. lightning-datatable also doesn't support modals itself unless you make a custom data type column.

Comment: @AtlasCan How can i use CSS here and the added image has a custom data type column

Comment: You need to use a custom data type, I haven't tried this but if you make a cell as a type of new component you can use it's click methods.

Answer (score 2):

More than two years late, but in case someone is wondering: It is possible.

"url field" is a bit misleading. If you want to open your modal window with something that appears to be a "url", make your column have data type "button". The [button](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button/example) has a variant "base", which makes it appear like a link. A column definition would look somewhat like this:

```javascript
{
        label: "My Column Title",
        type: "button",
        typeAttributes: {
            label: { fieldName: "SomeField__c" },
            name: "ActionName",
            variant: "base"
        }
    },
```

(The reference to SomeField__c is useful, when you use records of an SObject and want the text of the URL to be dynamic.)

Your data-table must have an attribute onrowaction, e.g.
`onrowaction={callRowAction}`.

You then add a handler for the click on the button:

```javascript
openModal = false;

callRowAction(event) {
    const selectedValue = event.detail.row.SomeField__c;
    const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
    if (actionName === "ActionName") {
        // init your modal here
        this.openModal = true;
    }
}
```

This assumes that you put your [modal](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/) in your markup in this way:

```html
<template if:true={openModal}>
<!-- here is your modal markup -->
</template>
```

In fact you might want to put your modal in another LWC.